# (C#)SendKeys.SendWait("{TAB}"); in java?

Tags: java

In C# it's `SendKeys.SendWait("{TAB}");`

What is that in java? (Sending the TAB keystroke) ?

I couldn't find a real answer in java and java docs didn't know what I was asking. (I'm notice at terms).

Thank youuu favorite site. =)

*EDIT:* I'm trying to send a tab key to an open notepad document to draw an ASCII picture and I just wanted a tab key instead of 3 spaces.

Comment: Sending it to what? That is Windows Forms method, thus being Windows specific. Java however is OS independent, so there can be no direct equivalent. You'll need to explain why you want do do that, what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I'm trying to send a tab key to an open notepad document to draw a ASCII picture and I just wanted a tab key instead of 3 spaces. Sounds pathetic I know, but I just want to make sure I was doing it right, using java to it's fullest

Comment: You asked a follow up question and I provided the suggestion to use the Robot two hours earlier. So much for providing timely feedback to your questions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
Component.transferFocus();
```

Or maybe you are looking for the KeyboardFocusManager focusNextComponent(...) method.

You can also use Component.dispatchEvent(...) where you create you own Tab KeyEvent.

> I'm trying to send a tab key to an open notepad document

Then you would need to use the Robot class. The above approaches are for using within a Java application, not an external application.

Comment: KeyboardFocusManager can send a TAB key to an open notepad text file?

Comment: @Kyle: That's not what you asked

Comment: I didn't realize you posted to use the robot class. I'm sorry I should have given the plus to you. Thank you.

Comment: @Kyle - neither did I... but it's easy to miss it (or hidden by the browser cache?)

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at the [java.awt.Robot](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) class.
It can be used to send keystrokes (simulate keyboard):

```
Robot robot = new Robot();  // AWTException if not supported
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
robot.delay(20);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
```

This will send TAB to the active application/window.

Comment: -1 for a duplicate posting. The suggestion to use a Robot was given 2 hours earlier.

Comment: @camickr - sorry, I haven't seen your edit (1.5 hours earlier) but I was occupied searching the link and writing a sample...

Comment: @camickr All you did was mention the Robot class in passing, you didn't explain it.  This answer is quite different from yours and complementary, not close to a dupe at all.

Comment: @MatthewRead, I introduced the poster to a new API. It is then their responsibility to read the API and understand how to use it. There is no need to spoon feed code. If the poster needs help than can post a follow up question to my posting at which time I can provide additional help. If code is posted then people become lazy and don't take the time to read the API to find out all the features available.

Comment: @camickr That's again entirely different from being a dupe.  You're not being consistent, and it's great that you're concerned with whether the OP learns something but that doesn't make this a bad answer. Anyways, just my opinion. Your downvotes are yours to spend as you like.

Comment: @MatthewRead, If somebody feels the answer isn't complete they can add comments (or edit the original suggestion) on how to make the answer more complete. There is no need to duplicate the suggestion, it clutters the forum. Also, at least I gave a reason for downvoting the question. You just downvoted mine answer for no reason.